# RHEL 6.6 - установил пакет mc. Не запускается. Ошибка:

Tags: linux, package, install, rhel, mc

> Error while loading shared libraries: libgpm.so.2: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

Делал так:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/mc/usr/bin (тут лежит бинарный файл mc);
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64 (тут лежит libgpm.so.2).
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменная окружения PATH никак(!!!) не связана с путём поиска so-шек. Если Вы хотите действовать через переменные окружения, сделайте так:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/.....
```

Но лучше сделать это "на века" используя утилиту

```
/sbin/ldconfig <Каталог, в котором лежит Ваша so-шка>
```

Утилита прокешит вашу библиотеку и запомнит её в системе в целом.

Comment: Это решение не сработало:
/sbin/ldconfig /usr/lib64

Comment: @Радик *Это решение не сработало* - можно более подробно? Что Вы сделали и какой получился результат?

Comment: /sbin/ldconfig /usr/lib64 - выполнил команду в точности, как вы сказали. Выполнилась без ошибок. Затем пытаюсь запустить mc. Ошибка. Та же самая. Error while loading shared libraries: libgpm.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory